# How to save where the user left off in a video

Tags: python, django

I am making a video lecture system such as www.udacity.com
When the user logs in, I have to save what courses they are registered in.
When the user also clicks and views a video and logs out, I have to save where they left off so that when they log back in, they will see where they were at in the video.

For example, if the user leaves at 0:50 and the user loads the video back on, I have to make sure that the video pops up at 0:50.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: You need to add more detail. How are you playing the videos? What is your environment?

Comment: I am using HTML5 videos and I am using Django/Python framework. After allowing a user to login, the user will see list of lectures. When the user clicks on a lecture video, the video will pop up and it will start from where the user left off.

Answer (score 4):

This tracks where you are in the video with Javascript and HTML:

HTML:

```
<video
    id="video-active"
    class="video-active"
    width="640"
    height="390"
    controls="controls">
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="current">0:00</div>
<div id="duration">0:00</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#video").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
      onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
    });
}

function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
    $("#current").text(currentTime);
    $("#duration").text(duration);
}
```

Note that this uses jQuery.

Bind window.beforeunload in Javascript with some function that sends the information to your server.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-controller-position

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame I don't have enough rep to upvote this.

Comment: It's fine if it helped you :)